Abnormal number of gesture recognizer dependencies: 100. System performance may be affected
In my IOS application I have a problem with menu when I start changing tabs (for example 20 times) I am getting error Abnormal number of gesture recognizer dependencies: 100. System performance may be affected. Please investigate reducing gesture recognizers and/or their dependencies. This error is because views are stacking and I click on 20 views in one time (I think this is a problem). When I left a button to go back and after open some views I will click "back" every thing is ok, so can I close my view when I go out.
//
//  BottomMenu.swift
//  SpaceManager
//
//  Created by Kuba Kromomołowski on 04/05/2024.
//

import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth

struct BottomMenu: View {
    
    @StateObject var logManager = MainViewModel()
    @StateObject var mvm = MenuViewModel()
    @State var condition1: Bool = true
    @State var condition2: Bool = false
    @State var condition3: Bool = false

//    @StateObject private var cameraViewModel = CameraViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            Group{
                
            Spacer()
            BtnMenu(btnText: "Dodaj",
                    btnIcon: "plus.app.fill",
                    destinationView:AnyView(LoggedMainView().navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)),
                    isActive: condition1
                    
            )
            Spacer()
            BtnMenu(btnText: "Szukaj", 
                    btnIcon: "magnifyingglass",
                    destinationView:AnyView(SearchView().navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)),
                    isActive: condition2
            )
            Spacer()
            BtnMenu(btnText: "Profil", 
                    btnIcon: "person.crop.circle.fill",
                    destinationView:AnyView(ProfileView().navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)),
                    isActive: condition3
            )
            Spacer()
          
        }.padding(.bottom, 30)
            .font(.system(size: 20))
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    BottomMenu()
}

//
//  BtnMenu.swift
//  SpaceManager
//
//  Created by Kuba Kromomołowski on 04/05/2024.
//

import SwiftUI

struct BtnMenu: View {
    var btnText: String
    var btnIcon: String
    var destinationView: AnyView

    @State var isActive: Bool = true
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink{
            destinationView
        }  label: {
            ZStack {
                Text("\(Image(systemName: btnIcon)) \(btnText)")
            }
        }.disabled(isActive)
       
       
    }
}


I tried to left back button and open some views and click back and everything was ok. I change NavigationLink to button but I can change view in this configuration, by I can use self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()

How are you instantiating and displaying BottomMenu?  Are you potentially creating multiple instances of it or is each view using the same instance?
